# Why is `sort List::Util::uniq(BAR, BAZ);` different from `sort &List::Util::uniq(BAR, BAZ);`

Tags: perl, prototype

I know `&` disables prototypes on but doesn't parentheses also do that. How are These two blocks of code different, and is there a reason that the top can **NOT** act like the bottom,

```perl
use List::Util;
use constant FOO => (1,2,3);
use constant BAR => (2,3,4,5,6);
use constant FOOBAR => sort List::Util::uniq(FOO, BAR);
```

```perl
use List::Util;
use constant FOO => (1,2,3);
use constant BAR => (2,3,4,5,6);
use constant FOOBAR => sort &List::Util::uniq(FOO, BAR);
```

Answer (score 3):

[sort](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#sort) is very special.

> Warning: syntactical care is required when sorting the list
> returned from a function. If you want to sort the list returned by
> the function call "find_records(@key)", you can use:

> ```
>            my @contact = sort { $a cmp $b } find_records @key;
>            my @contact = sort +find_records(@key);
>            my @contact = sort &find_records(@key);
>            my @contact = sort(find_records(@key));
> ```

> If instead you want to sort the array @key with the comparison
> routine "find_records()" then you can use:

> ```
>            my @contact = sort { find_records() } @key;
>            my @contact = sort find_records(@key);
>            my @contact = sort(find_records @key);
>            my @contact = sort(find_records (@key));
> ```

Comment: Can you color a bit more as to why it's special? Is this a parser trick to make `sort` work? Can you speak as to how it's implemented that makes it so special and if other things do this?

Comment: SUBNAME doesn't appear anywhere else in [perlfunc](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc), so this behaviour is unique among Perl functions. Historic reasons I'd guess.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the heuristics involved in guessing which of `sort`'s calling convention you are using.

---

`sort` has a complicated syntax, with three fundamental calling conventions:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
sort LIST
sort BLOCK LIST
sort SUBNAME LIST
```

These alternative calling conventions introduce numerous ambiguities, including these:

- `sort {` could be the start for `sort BLOCK LIST` or `sort LIST`.<sup>[2]</sup>
- `sort foo` could be the start for `sort SUBNAME LIST` or `sort LIST`.<sup>[2]</sup>

As a result, the parser must often "guess". The issue at hand is that you want `sort List::Util::uniq(FOO, BAR)` to be parsed as `sort LIST`, but the parser "guessed" you were using `sort FUNCTION LIST`.

Preceding the expression with `&` prevents it from being treated as a `SUBNAME`, but it also overrides any prototype the sub might have. The following are alternative workarounds without that drawback:

```perl
sort( List::Util::uniq(FOO, BAR) )
```

```perl
sort +List::Util::uniq(FOO, BAR)
```

```perl
sort { $a cmp $b } List::Util::uniq(FOO, BAR)
```

---

1. This is a simplification, since it doesn't factor in parens.
2. `LIST` just means a generic expression evaluated in list context. Expressions can start with `{` or an identifier.

Comment: Can prototypes make `function(arg1, arg2)` parse as a `function` with `(arg1, arg2)` being parsed as a list and not an argument too it? I didn't know prototypes could even do tat.

Comment: `sort` has no prototype.